# How to implement reaction to EPSV (ALL) command in my FTP server?

Tags: java, sockets, ftp

I'm trying to set up FTP server in Java on my local network via Wi-Fi. And I'm stuck with handling `EPSV ALL` command. As a client I use VLC player on iPhone. It is sending `EPSV ALL` to the server when I'm trying to play .mp4 file. Server response with this line:

```
"229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||" + freeDataPort + "|)"
```

The server creates `serverSocket` on `freeDataPort`, listens to income connection and nothing happens.

I've tried open movie with connection to FileZilla server - it works. Also I can't understand why client trying to establish second connection (connection that request user and pass again) after this command (`EPSV`) while `PASV` command creates data connection and do simple data transmission, like response to `LIST`, handled in first one.

This is handler for `EPSV` that I use:

```
private void handleEpsv() {
    sendMsgToClient("229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||" + freeDataPort + "|)");
    try {
        dataSocket = new ServerSocket(freeDataPort);
        System.out.println("waiting for connect... port: " + freeDataPort);
        dataConnection = dataSocket.accept();
        dataOutWriter = new PrintWriter(dataConnection.getOutputStream(), true);
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        debugOutput("Could not create data connection.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

That what it result at the last time:

```
FTP Server started listening on port 21
{/192.168.0.105=INITIALThread-0    Threads in data list: 0}
New connection received. Worker was created.
from INITIAL THREAD
Thread-0 - send to client:    220 Welcome to the FTP-Server

USER a from INITIAL THREAD
Thread-0 - send to client:    331 User name okay, need password

PASS a from INITIAL THREAD
Thread-0 - send to client:    230 User logged in successfully

SYST from INITIAL THREAD
Thread-0 - send to client:    215 UNIX Type: L8

PWD from INITIAL THREAD
Thread-0 - send to client:    257 "/"

TYPE I from INITIAL THREAD
Thread-0 - send to client:    200 OK

CWD // from INITIAL THREAD
Thread-0 - send to client:    250 CWD successful. / is current directory

PASV from INITIAL THREAD
Thread-0 - send to client:    227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,0,199,7,232)

waiting for connect... port: 2024
Data connection - Passive Mode - established
LIST from INITIAL THREAD
Thread-0 - send to client:    125 Opening ASCII mode data connection for file list.

from INITIAL THREAD
Thread-0 - send to client:    226 Transfer complete.

{/192.168.0.105=INITIALThread-0    Threads in data list: 1}
New connection received. Worker was created.

Thread-1 - send to client:    220 Welcome to the FTP-Server

FEAT 
Thread-1 - send to client:    211-Features:


Thread-1 - send to client:    MDTM


Thread-1 - send to client:    REST STREAM


Thread-1 - send to client:    SIZE


Thread-1 - send to client:    MLST type*;size*;modify*;


Thread-1 - send to client:    MLSD


Thread-1 - send to client:    UTF8


Thread-1 - send to client:    CLNT


Thread-1 - send to client:    MFMT


Thread-1 - send to client:    EPSV


Thread-1 - send to client:    EPRT


Thread-1 - send to client:    211 END

USER a 
Thread-1 - send to client:    331 User name okay, need password

PASS a 
Thread-1 - send to client:    230 User logged in successfully

EPSV ALL 
Thread-1 - send to client:    229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||2025|)

used by Thread-1 Thread DATA type
waiting for connect... port: 2025
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EPSV ALL` is not `EPSV`. `EPSV ALL` has a special meaning. It is used by the client to indicate that it will only ever use the `EPSV`, not `PASV`, `PORT` nor `EPRT`. You should respond only something like `200 OK` to it. You should read [RFC 2428](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2428#section-4).

Actually I've never seen any FTP client using this command. Most servers will ignore it or handle it incorrectly. The reason why VLC fails to talk to your server is probably that in addition to responding incorrectly, you block your control connecting waiting for the incoming data transfer. And VLC is sending further commands and times out waiting for your server response (and consequently it possibly retries by opening a new connection).

This is a transcript of VLC connection to FileZilla FTP server. Note that FileZilla also handles `EPSV ALL` incorrectly, by responding with `229 Entering Extended Passive Mode`. But it does not block the control connection and correctly handles the following commands (including later `EPSV`).

```
230 Logged on
EPSV ALL
229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||65079|)
TYPE I
200 Type set to I
SIZE video.avi
213 119035510
EPSV
229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||63465|)
TYPE I
200 Type set to I
RETR video.avi
150 Opening data channel for file download from server of "/video.avi"
...
```

---

Actually even if the command was a normal `EPSV`, you should not block the control connection, as the client will be sending further commands, particularly the `RETR` (or `STOR`, `LIST`, `MLSD`...).

Comment: That's worked, thank you! Turns out that VLC player wants you to create three different threads if you want to get a video stream, and I blocked the second.

Comment: @RomanFrolov On a side note, when responding to PASV or EPSV for an actual transfer, do not send the reply to the client until after the listening port is actually open and listening first. If the port fails to open, send a failure reply instead. Your `handleEpsv()` is not doing either of those. As soon at the client receives a success reply, it will try to connect, which will fail if you don't actually have the port open yet